# Submenu Magento 1.9 not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, submenu

for my shop project i am working with Magento 1.9 Mobile Version. Everything works fine as i wish but there is one Problem i cant fix.

The Menu (Navigation) in the Mobile Version doesn't show Sub-Menu Category's. 
Can i build them in, in an easy way?
I thought i destroyed the code during my creation Process but its the same as on the demo store:

enterprise-demo.user.magentotrial.com/

Think i have to include something in the CSS file or in the menu.js?

Cant figure it out. Might be interesting for others to.

The helper get a German beer.

Answer (score 2):

I think i found a solution, after looking for hours onto google i found it myself.

Thank you all for viewing. To Tell you its in the renderer.phtml file change it like this an it will work.

```
$html = '';

$children = $menuTree->getChildren(); $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel(); $childLevel = is_null($parentLevel) ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

$counter = 1; $childrenCount = $children->count();

$parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass(); $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

foreach ($children as $child) {
    $child->setLevel($childLevel);
    $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
    $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
    $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

    $outermostClassCode = 'level'. $childLevel;
    $_hasChildren = ($child->hasChildren()) ? 'has-children' : '';

    $html .= '<li '. $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) .'>';

    $html .= '<a href="'. $child->getUrl() .'" class="'. $outermostClassCode .' '. $_hasChildren .'">'. $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) .'</a>';

    if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
        $html .= '<div class="'. $childrenWrapClass .'">';
    }

    $nextChildLevel = $childLevel + 1;

    if (!empty($_hasChildren)) {
        $html .= '<ul class="level'. $childLevel .'">';
        $html .=     '<li class="level'. $nextChildLevel .'">';
        $html .=         '<a class="level'. $nextChildLevel .'" href="'. $child->getUrl() .'">';
        /*$html .=             $this->__('View All ') . $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName()));*/
        $html .=         '</a>';
        $html .=     '</li>';
        $html .=     $this->render($child, $childrenWrapClass);
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }

    if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
        $html .= '</div>';
    }

    $html .= '</li>';

    $counter++; }

return $html;
```